# How to mock PushNotification and ionic.Platform.isAndroid() in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, unit-testing, ionic-framework

We develop an app with Cordova and Ionic framework and use phonegap-plugin-push. Things are working quite fine, but I'd like to write some unit tests for our Push functionality with Karma and Jasmine.

We have a factory `PushNotificationService` with a function `register()` , which is called when the user enables PushNotifications in the app settings. For now, I just want to unit test that `PushNotification.init(...)` is called when `register()` has been called.

However, this does not work as expected for two reasons:

1. PhantomJS (which we use for the karma tests) is no mobile device, so ionic.Platform.isAndroid() and `ionic.Platform.isIOS()` return false and `PushNotification.init(...)` is never called. The test fails with `Expected spy init to have been called.`
2. If I simply remove the if-statement checking for the platform, the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: PushNotification` is thrown.

While I was looking for a solution, I wondered where the `ionic.Platform` object and the PushNotification object are defined. Both are defined in the root scope (on the same level as angular and window).

Does anybody know a possibility to spy and mock function in global (root scope) variables? 
Or do you know another solution for my test case?

**PushNotificationService**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('PushNotificationService', function () {

function register() {
  if (ionic.Platform.isIPad() || ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
    var push = PushNotification.init({
      android: {
        senderID: "***********",
        icon: "icon",
        forceShow: true
      },
      ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
      },
      windows: {}
    });

    push.on('registration', onRegistration);
    push.on('notification', onNotification);
    push.on('error', onError);
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
describe('PushNotificationService', function () {

  beforeEach(module('myApp', function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('PushNotification', {
      init: jasmine.createSpy('init')
    });

    // try to mock ionic.Platform.isAndroid(), as PhantomJS is neither Android nor iOS
    $provide.value('ionic', {
      Platform: {
        isAndroid: function () {
          return true;
        }
      }
    })
  }));

  var PushNotificationService;
  var PushNotification;

  beforeEach(inject(function (_PushNotificationService_, _PushNotification_) {
    PushNotificationService = _PushNotificationService_;
    PushNotification = _PushNotification_;
  }));

  it('should call PushNotification.init()', function () {
    PushNotificationService.register();
    expect(PushNotification.init).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you do it? Were you able to fix your problem?